# Azure alternative to spring cloud dataflow process

Tags: spring, azure, azureservicebus, azure-eventhub, spring-cloud-dataflow

I'm looking for the azure alternative for the Data flow model of Data Source-processor-sink.
I want the three entities to be separate microservices. I want to use messaging as a link between these three. 
Basically, Source app takes the data from another service and sends it to processor while processor app acts on it and sends relevant notification/alert to sink. 
I'm aware I can use rabbitmq for the messaging but I need to know which one will be better in azure - service bus topics or eventhub? and how can I use them?

Answer (score 0):

At the moment, there isn't a Spring Cloud Stream [binder implementation](https://github.com/spring-cloud?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=binder&type=&language=) for Azure Event Hubs.

Unless we have this, the [out-of-the-box](https://github.com/spring-cloud-stream-app-starters/) or the custom apps cannot be built as a messaging-microservice app, where Spring Cloud Stream provides the programming model and Spring Cloud Data Flow lets you orchestrate the individual microserivces in to a data pipeline *(i.e., source-processor-sink)* via the DSL/Drag-and-Drop GUI.

Microsoft was exploring the binder implementation in the past; possibly it would end up in [Azure Spring Boot](https://github.com/Microsoft/azure-spring-boot) project. Feel free to drop an issue on their backlog.